# Separate values of a field

Tags: php

I have the field in table , the value is such a (24114A23)
I want read this separately(23 A 114 24),and show on dropdwon box 
for example.

23  on dropdwon1
A   on dropdwon2
114 on dropdown3
23  on dropdwon4

Comment: How do you know where to split the string?

Comment: I'd say if your table is like that, the table's the problem, not splitting it. Otherwise, if it's always with a fixed size, you can use substring to start splitting it.

Comment: Please supply more information about your question.  You do not make it clear whether the format of the string is always >2 digits, 3 digits, 1 letter, 2 dgits< ,  nor do you show any attempt as to what you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your Values have the same format all the time, you can use a regular expressions thatfor: `/([0-9]{2})([0-9]{3})([a-zA-Z])([0-9]{2})/`

Living example: https://regex101.com/r/wA4lT6/1

Comment: without more information from @user1875505 , this is the best solution.  Could also offer up a substring.

Comment: Yes substring would work too, but end up in more Code.

Comment: agreed.  for the limited amount of information provided by the person asking the question, the extra effort isn't really worth it. :)

Answer (score 2):

**This is not really an answer but an addition** to @lippoliv's answer, just for the sake of completenes and it would be too long and ugly as a comment.

If you call [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match.php) like

```
$re = "/([0-9]{2})([0-9]{3})([a-zA-Z])([0-9]{2})/"; 
preg_match($re, "24114A23", $matches);
```

you can access the different regex groups by using the group index as an index for the output array provided (see the [preg_match documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match.php)), so if you wanted to get the content of match group 2 for example, which in this case would be "114"

[image]

get it by writing `$matches[2]`.